# saving and loading datas with json or pickle

Tags: python, json, load, save, pickle

**I´ll leave this here for archive and stuff but will update the code below to a working one since i were able to fix my issue (if any linux user reads this maybe you can help me with a linux support or test if the windows method works for you**

1st of all I am an unexpirienced and not native english person .

I wrote a little time table and got to the point where I wanted to save the data the user entered for a next execution of the program. So I experimented a little with json / pickle and didnt got really far so I gonna request help :) . I am aware that I have to change every **init**() after I got a loading method but I will try to generate an empty standard file for the case that there is no saved data. I am also aware that the method save() has a terrible name because it doesnt save it only returns data . I am also aware that the code of the code isnt english but I can translate on request and since it`s not really about the cod it self (even though I am glad of feedback) only about the save/load of data I guess it`s okay. In the process of working witht he code I got to a question (well actually 2) How can I save the data the user entered/which is automatically generated into a list of of lists which 11 dicts each ? (from the format : 1 week with 5 days and 11 hours each) and will load() work if I am able to save the data like this ?
Here`s my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import platform
import sys
import json
import pprint
import time
import pickle
class stunde:

    def __init__(self):

        self.daten = {}

    def start(self):

        self.daten = {'Fach': "    ", 'Raum': "    ", 'Lehrer': "    "}


    def aendern(self,was,information):

        if was in self.daten:
           self.daten[was] = information
        else:
           print('Fehler bei der Eingabe bitte auch Groß/Kleinschreibeung beachten')

    def anzeigen(self):

        print ("       ",self.daten )

    def save (self):

        return self.daten

    def load(self,data):
        self.daten={}
        self.daten=data


    def raum(self):

        print("Raum : ",self.daten['Raum'])


class tag:

    def __init__(self):

        self.stunden = []


    def start(self):
        for i in range(11):
            std = stunde()
            self.stunden.append(std)
            self.stunden.start()

    def aendern(self,tagwas,was,information):

        if len(self.stunden)>=(tagwas-1):
            self.stunden[tagwas-1].aendern(was,information)
        else:
            print("Dieser tag hat nur " , len(self.stunden) , "Stunden. Bitte eine dieser wählen")

    def anzeigen(self):

        for i in range(len(self.stunden)):
            print(i+1)
            self.stunden[i].anzeigen()

    def save (self):

        datas=[]
        for i in range(len(self.stunden)):
            datas.append(self.stunden[i].save())
        return datas

    def load(self,data):

        #hier muss 1 liste mit 11 dicts übergeben werden wenn :
        for x in data:
            t = stunde();
            t.load(x);
            self.stunden.append(t)

    def raum(self):

        for i in range(len(self.stunden)):
            print(i+1),self.stunden[i].raum()

class woche:

    def __init__(self):

        self.tage = []
        self.start()

    def start(self):

        laufpfad=os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
        dateiposition="\datas\data"
        checkpfad="".join((laufpfad,dateiposition))
        if os.path.exists(checkpfad)==True:
            with open(checkpfad,"rb") as filename:
                data=pickle.load(filename)
            self.load(data)
            print("Daten erfolgreich geladen")
        else:
            for i in range(5):
                day = tag()
                self.tage.append(day)
                self.tage.start()
            print("Keine Daten gefunden")



    def aendern(self,wochewas,tagwas,was,information):

        if len(self.tage)>=(wochewas-1):
            self.tage[wochewas-1].aendern(tagwas,was,information)
        else:
            print("Diese Woche hat nur " , len(self.tage) , "Tage zur Auswahl. Bitte einen dieser wählen")

    def anzeigen(self , ouf = sys.stderr):

        for i in range(len(self.tage)):
            if i == 0 :
                print("Montag ",file = ouf),self.tage[0].anzeigen()
            if i == 1 :
                print("Dienstag ",file = ouf),self.tage[1].anzeigen()
            if i == 2 :
                print("Mittwoch ",file = ouf),self.tage[2].anzeigen()
            if i == 3 :
                print("Donnerstag ",file = ouf),self.tage[3].anzeigen()
            if i == 4 :
                print("Freitag ",file = ouf),self.tage[4].anzeigen()


    def save(self):
        aktuell = platform.system()
        if aktuell=='Windows':
                print("Windows detected as OS!")
                ordner=os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
                neuerordner=os.path.join(ordner,"datas")
                if os.path.exists(neuerordner)== False:
                    os.mkdir(neuerordner)
                else:
                    data =[]
                    for i in range(len(self.tage)):
                        it=self.tage[i].save()
                        data.append(it)
                    neuerpfad=os.path.join(neuerordner,"data")
                    with open(neuerpfad,"wb") as filename:
                        data2save=data
                        pickle.dump(data2save,filename)
                    filename.close
                    print("Daten erfolgreich gespeichert")

        elif aktuell=='Linux':
                print("Linux detected as OS")

        else:
            print("Dein Betriebssystem ,",aktuell,"wird leider nicht unterstützt")



    def load(self,data):
        pprint.pprint(data)
        print("#################################")
#hier liegt ein FEHLER die daten werden fehlerhaft eingelesen oder garnicht
        for x in data:
            t = tag();
            t.load(x);
            self.tage.append(t)


    def raum(self , ouf = sys.stderr):

        for i in range(len(self.tage)):
            print("Tag ", i+1 , file = ouf ),self.tage[i].raum()

def main():
    week=woche()
    eingabe = ""
    while 1:
        print()
        print(" Eintragungen zu einem (T)ag ändern? ")
        print(" Wochenplanplan (a)nzeigen? ")
        print(" (R)aumplan der Woche anzeigen")
        print(" Einen (b)estimmten Tag anzeigen?")
        print(" Den Raumplan (f)ür einen bestimmten Tag anzeigen?")
        print(" (E)nde? ")
        print()
        eingabe = input(' Ihre Wahl? ')
        print()
        if eingabe in ['t','T']:
            while True:
                wochewas =(input('Welchen Tag wollen Sie bearbeiten? (Bitte Zahl angeben!) '))
                try:
                    wochewas = int(wochewas)
                    break
                except ValueError :
                    print("Nur Zahlen eingeben bitte")
            while True :
                tagwas = (input('Welche Stunde wollen Sie bearbeiten? (Bitte Zahl angeben!) '))
                try:
                    tagwas = int(tagwas)
                    break
                except ValueError :
                    print("Nur Zahlen eingeben bitte")
            stdwas = input('Welche Information wollen Sie eintragen? (Fach, Raum oder Lehrer?) ').title()
            inf = input('Was soll eingetragen werden?(Maximal 4 Zeichen) ')[:4].ljust(4)
            week.aendern(wochewas,tagwas,stdwas,inf)
        elif eingabe in ['a','A']:
            week.anzeigen()
        elif eingabe in ['r','R']:
            week.raum()
        elif eingabe in ['b','B']:
            while True:
                was=input("Welchen Tag wollen sie anzeigen lassen ? (Nur Zahlen bitte !")
                try:
                    was=int(was)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Nur Zahlen eingeben bitte!")
            week.tage[was-1].anzeigen()
        elif eingabe in ['f','F']:
            while True:
                was=input("Von welchem Tag wollen sie den Raumplan anzeigen lassen ?(Nur Zahlen bittte!)")
                try:
                    was=int(was)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Nur Zahlen bitte!")
            week.tage[was-1].raum()
        elif eingabe in["e","E"]:
                warten=input('Bitte nochmal Enter drücken! ')
                week.save()
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Bye Bye")
                #sys.exit()
                os._exit(0)
        elif eingabe in ['s','S']:

            week.save()

        elif eingabe in ['l','L']:
            pfad=os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
            datas=r"\datas"
            data=r"\data"
            echterpfad="".join((pfad,datas,data))
            with open(echterpfad,"rb") as file:
                weekdata=pickle.load(file)
            #pprint.pprint(weekdata)
            week.load(weekdata)
        else :
            print("Bitte ein Buchstaben aus den Klammern oben wählen!")


print("Ihr Stundenplaner wurde geladen!")
main()
```

Comment: You should post your code here: 1) edit your post and paste your code in, 2) select your code and press Ctrl+K (or Command+K on the Mac)

Comment: done :) but I thought the pb-highlighting is nicer

Answer (score 0):

I speak German, so I can read your code.  However, it's **long**, and a bit cryptic, so when I tried it, I wasn't able to see right off what the code should do in all cases.

However, I do have two suggestions:

1) You are doing a `json.dumps` and a `pickle.load`… why?  If you want to write objects to a file, you should be using `dump` and `load` from the same serializer.

2) Since you are working with classes, I'd probably use `dill` as opposed to `json` or `pickle`, as you will have a better chance of things serializing as you want them to.

So for `dill`, you'd use `dill.dump` and `dill.load'… like this:

```
>>> t = 'Mon'
>>> w = 2
>>> 
>>> import dill 
>>> 
>>> f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
>>> dill.dump(t, f)
>>> dill.dump(w, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> f = open('data.txt', 'rb')
>>> _t = dill.load(f)
>>> _w = dill.load(f)
>>> _t
'Mon'
>>> _w
2
>>> f.close()
```

It's the same interface for `pickle` and for `json`.
And if you don't want to to multiple `dump` and `load`,
then you can put everything into a tuple, and do it all at once.

```
>>> f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
>>> dill.dump((t, w), f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> f = open('data.txt', 'rb')
>>> _t,_w = dill.load(f)
>>> f.close()
```

So, for something that should look like your data structure, you can do this:

```
>>> cal = [[{1:'a'},{2:'b'}],[{3:'c'},{4:'d'}]] 
>>> with open('foo.txt', 'wb') as f:
...   dill.dump(cal, f)
... 
>>> with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as f:
...   cal_ = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> cal_
[[{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}], [{3: 'c'}, {4: 'd'}]]
>>>
```

Comment: The night was long and I worked on it aliitle (only a little) I guess I found a quite acceptable way to load the data but therefore I need a way to save generated data in a list of 5 lists of 11 dicts (like week with 5 days with 11 hours each) I'll try tp uodate the main thread or paste it in an answer

Comment: i decided to not use dill since it doesnt seem to be standard implmented (import dill return error) and I`ll use this over different platforms ( as you could see in my fresh code) and went back to pickle here's the updated code http://pastebin.com/ZKJfhuM3 tell me what you think bout it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "import dill return error"… but if you mean that it's not shipped with python, that's correct.  You have to install it in addition to python (like this: `pip install dill`).  Then you can do: `import dill`.

Comment: With your changed code, you apparently don't need the `json` import any longer, but it looks like it might work if pickle can pickle your target objects.  If so, you should be done with this question.  If you run into any serialization issues, I would suggest you try `dill` again.  It is supported on all major platforms, you just need to make sure it's installed everywhere.